# add variables to list and assign values to them in a loop?

Tags: c#

I have a few parameters from a different class `AnalogGlitch`, which I want to assign within this code. Instead of assigning values to them individually, I want to pack them in a list and to this in a loop.

However from the output I can see that the values of the variables to not change at all. I have not used as much C# before and wonder if this is something specific to the language (and not in python for example)?

The code works finde, when I assign values to the variables individually instead of in a loop ...

```
public class SlenderInView : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AnalogGlitch glitch;

    private bool isLooking = false;

    private List<float> controls = new List<float>();

    void Start()
    {
        glitch = GetComponent<AnalogGlitch>();

        controls.Add(glitch.scanLineJitter);
        controls.Add(glitch.horizontalShake);
        controls.Add(glitch.colorDrift);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // removed the code dealing with isLooking

        if (isLooking)
        {   
            for(int i=0; i<controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if(controls[i] < 1)
                {
                    controls[i] += (float)0.1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {    
            for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
            {
                controls[i] += 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the *values* of the variables to the list - you're not adding the variables themselves. So when you change the content of the list, that won't affect the variables at all. As a simpler example:

```
int x = 10;
List<int> values = new List<int>();
values.Add(x); // Add the *current value of x* to the list
values[0] = 20; // This doesn't change the value of x
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

So the behaviour you're seeing is definitely what I'd expect. There's no easy way of achieving the behaviour you want without bigger changes. You could write something like an `Int32Holder` class, and change the `AnalogGlitch` variables to be of type `Int32Holder`, then create a `List<Int32Holder>`, etc... but I suspect it would be simpler just to hard-code the use of the variables:

```
glitch.scanLineJitter = MaybeUpdate(glitch.scanLineJitter);
glitch.horizontalShake = MaybeUpdate(glitch.horizontalShake);
glitch.colorDrift = MaybeUpdate(glitch.colorDrift);
```

Or pass the variables by reference to a method:

```
MaybeUpdate(ref glitch.scanLineJitter);
MaybeUpdate(ref glitch.horizontalShake);
MaybeUpdate(ref glitch.colorDrift);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `glitch.scanLineJitter`, `glitch.horizontalShake` and `glitch.colorDrift` are `value types`, meaning that when you add them to your list, you actually create a copy of the value they hold. Writing

```cs
controls[i] += (float)0.1;
```

does *not* change the original variable, it just changes the value contained inside the list, which was a copy of the original.